# LibGDX - Check if currently on Android/Desktop

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX and flixel-android to build a Desktop/Android game. It feels like there should be a way of checking to see if you're currently being run on an Android device, the Desktop, and so on, but I can't find it anywhere. Am I supposed to just pass it down from the individual launchers? Surely LibGDX can just tell me?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you're after [Application querying](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationQuerying)

```
switch(Gdx.app.getType()) {
   case ApplicationType.Android:
       // android specific code
   case ApplicationType.Desktop:
       // desktop specific code
   case ApplicationType.WebGl:
       /// HTML5 specific code
}
```

Comment: For reference: this has been changed to Gdx.app.getType()

Comment: Can you detect whether it is Windows or Mac?

Comment: @LimThyeChean https://stackoverflow.com/q/228477/5771029

Answer (score 8):

Magd's code may have worked at one stage, it didn't with my version of GDX, or certainly not my implementation anyway. I had to change it as follows:

```
switch(Gdx.app.getType()) {
       case Android:
           // android specific code
           TouchPadController.createTouchPad();
       case Desktop:
           // desktop specific code
       case WebGL:
           /// HTML5 specific code
```

}

Comment: What version is this? The latest nightly?